# How to create a dynamic carousal for Facebook messenger in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

2 questions:

1. How to get Facebook Page scope user ID (psid) ? the call for agent `agent.originalRequest.payload.data.sender.id` is not working in V2
2. How to add a dynamic carousal showing products from the database (Firebase)?

Is the correct option would be to integrate graph API into Dialogflow? if it how you do that?

Comment: what do you mean by dymanic ? can you please explain bit more

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya I mean that I would like to feel the amount of the products and the data using calls from database, one function that will work for different users based and what they asked from the bot beforehand, nothing special but I have no idea how to do it in Dialogflow

Comment: it would be good if you can put your code, whatever you have tried so far